# Host to use Microsoft Visual SourceSafe or CVS on web hosting for development?

Tags: asp.net, hosting, cvs, visual-sourcesafe

Host to use Microsoft Visual SourceSafe or CVS  on web hosting for development?

Comment: Microsoft is dropping support for it April 2011.

Comment: What I should choose for do it?

Comment: and How to use on web hosting? CVS is ok?

Comment: if you are a bit of a masochist, here is a link about how to setup vss for the internet http://alinconstantin.homeip.net/webdocs/scc/vss_internet.htm - Note - I dont use it - and as others have mentioned, i wouldnt recommend it to my enemies. :-) Check out svn instead (it has its detractors too). You can also consider using some distributed source control system like git /mercurial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with the question "Why VSS or CVS"? Is this because of a legacy reasons, or is it because you don't know other options?

If the answer is "because of legacy", then you don't have much choices. There are no cloud providers that offer VSS support, and the choices for CVS are not that great either. SourceForge.net still offers CVS support, and searching for "CVS hosting" also yields some results, but most are not well-known names with proven reliability and security.

However, given what your choices are, I would be quite interested to hear more details about a legacy project that uses both VSS *and* CVS. :-)

If, however, the answer is "because I don't know what else is there", I would strongly recommend to look into SVN, Mercurial or GIT. There are great cloud providers that offer support for these three ranging from free for open source projects to multiple tiers of paid support for proprietary projects. And it's quite easy to set servers for any of these three yourself. Not to mention that all of them are orders of magnitude better than VSS and CVS.

To give you a quick start, here's a short list of providers you can look at:

- [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) - SVN and Mercurial support, free for open source projects, but there's control over the visibility of your source
- [GitHub](https://github.com/) - GIT support, free plans for open source, paid plans for proprietary projects
- [Google Code](http://code.google.com/projecthosting/) - SVN and Mercurial support, free 2GB for open source projects, though they do have some control over the visibility of your source
- [BitBucket](http://www.bitbucket.org) - SVN and Mercurial support, free for 5 users, unlimited for paid and proprietary projects
- [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/) - GIT, SVN, Mercurial, and CVS support, free for open source projects
- [Unfuddle](http://www.unfuddle.com) - GIT and SVN support, paid
- [CodebaseHQ](http://codebasehq.com) - GIT, Mercurial and  SVN support, paid

There are a lot more out there, with various pricing models (and reliability of course :-))

**Update**: If you are working on a web app, your web host dos necessarily have to support also the source control. You can have your sources (HTML, CSS, JS) in a separate version control host, and deploy to the web host only the final version of your work.

Answer (score 0):

CVS requires a CVS server to be running (/ available) and I'd be willing the bet that SourceSafe would require the same.
When you get web hosting normally you just get a place to store files and some server software will make it available over http.

I originally thought that this question read "How to use...". Upon double checking the question, "Host to use..." doesn't completely make sense. Hopefully the information I've presented is useful.

Comment: If I rent web hosting on internet,I have to find that web hosting it have these version control,Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [svnhostingcomparison.com](http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com/) for a list of SVN providers.

Answer (score 0):

**Use CVS for web development**

try cvsdude.com

Just create a stand alone local repository (unless you are on a team, see note below).  TortoiseCVS is great for Windows as you can integrate it with the shell and get a right click context sensitive menu. Be sure to add the CVS keywords `$RCSfile: $` and `$Revision: $` to your HTML files.  This will allow you to tell the file(s) name and version that create a web page you are viewing/debugging.
Like this: `<!-- $RCSfile: $ $Revision: $ -->`
When you check it in CVS will change it to: `<!-- $RCSfile: keyword.html,v $ $Revision: 1.3 $ -->`.

Here is an online reference:
http://www.badgertronics.com/writings/cvs/index.html

**Note:**  If you are in a dev group you will want a server.  There are some security issues, so read the docs.  Also, there is an awesome Apache module for CVS that will let you browse and compare code versions.  It also colorizes the source, shows who/when changes were made, etc.